# Walk through elements in a Range object and change them

Tags: javascript, dom

How to walk through elements in a Range object with an ability to change them?

### Use case:

An extension which is supposed will to take an user selection and wrap some text occurences in it (references to laws) in links.

### To do this we need:

1. to walk through all the elements in a Range object
2. replace contents of some text nodes with the same text, but with added links.

I know how to do the first step:

```
var sel = document.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(range.cloneContents(), NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
var node;
while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
  console.log(node);
  // we have a copy of an original text node here and can use a text of it
  // and can't change a text of an original node, just a text of copied one
}
```

I used [Range.cloneContents()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/cloneContents) function above, which makes document fragment from copied elements of Range object. May be there is a way to make a document fragment from an original elements in Range object? I haven't found such a function ... There is an another similar function - [Range.extractContents()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents), but it removes elements from document.